# Display:Table-Cell width issues

Tags: html, css, tablecell

I have set fixed pixel width values for a three column layout, and want to use `display:table-cell` properties so that the columns will always snap to the height of the column div with the largest content.

I have used this technique before no problem, but I now can't seem to get the column width to fix, and instead, if the content in a div increases it makes the div wider instead of taller, at the same time this compresses the width of the adjacent cells. Obviously the whole point I'm using table-cell is to stop this happening, can anyone see what is stopping the column widths working? In the JSFiddle the widths initially look correct but if you add extra text into any of the columns you will see that it doesn't respond as I need it to.

[JSFiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/sa3jefyg/)

The html/css below are as per the JSFiddle above:

```
<div class="container">
<div class="fwcol">
    <div class="col">
        <div class="thirds">COLUMN1</div>
        <div class="thirdm">COLUMN2</div>
        <div class="thirds">COLUMN3</div>
    </div><!--col-->
</div><!--fwcol-->
</div><!--container-->

.container {
    margin: 0 auto;
    width: 966px;
    background:red;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.fwcol {
    float: left;
    width: 966px;
}
.col {
    width:966px;
    display:table;
    border-collapse:separate;
    border-spacing:20px;
}
.thirds, .thirdm {
    display: table-cell;
    padding: 20px;
    background: #FFF;
}
.thirds {
    width: 255px;
}
.thirdm {
    width: 256px;
}
```

Comment: your fiddle seems to work fine when adding text: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sa3jefyg/1/ - as you can see the cols get taller not wider

Comment: @Danield see: [link](http://www.0urs.com/columns.jpg) this is what I get when I add more text. Have tried in Firefox and Chrome to the same effect. Totally bemused!

Comment: Follow Ali's advice: http://jsfiddle.net/danield770/sa3jefyg/3/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add these two properties to .col class:

```
display:table;
table-layout:fixed;
```

You may also add  `"word-wrap:break-word;"` to child divs to prevent overflow.

Comment: @Danield @Ali I have tried this, and yes, it does seem to solve the problem in this instance. I still don't understand why it doesn't work without these additional properties, it only works with `word-wrap:break-word` included in all child divs. I have a two column layout on the same page sitting within the same containing div structure and it works fine without any of these additional properties. Just finding this a real confusion!

Comment: If you test your two-columned layout with a long word (with no space), the problem remains.

Comment: Yes that's true, but I still don't have to specify a fixed table layout for the two column layout to work correctly. In my example in the question, without the word wrap property added the text will overflow the div even if it is a sentence of words shorter than the width of the div. Do you know why this is?